# When i am using <code><hr /></code> tag in wordpress codeeditor it turns into a ruler

Tags: wordpress, editor, wpml, wp-editor

i am facing this problem . that whrn i am using a

```
 <code><hr /></code>
```

in wp code editor it turns into a horizontal ruler . more over '`</`' is not showing when i using `<code></code>`

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Code_in_Your_Posts#Code_Within_Paragraphs):

> Using the `<code>` tag doesn't tell WordPress to encode HTML markup
>   within the tag or strip it from the post. WordPress thinks that you
>   are using this markup for formatting, leaving it untouched.

To avoid this behavior, use character entities or extended characters to represent the left and right arrow characters in a way that is not recognized as the beginning and end of an HTML tag by a web browser, like this:

`<code>&lt;hr /&gt;</code>`